# How to combine two JavaScript arrays into one JSON?

Tags: javascript

I want send two arrays `$scope.candidates` and `$scope.managers` as POST to some PHP which I will code for the server. I strongly prefer a JSON interface, and thought to combine them into a single JSON object.

```
    var JsonString = {'candiates' : JSON.stringify($scope.candidates),
                      'managers'  : JSON.stringify($scope.managers)
                     };
```

Does not generate valid JSON. How do I achieve what I want?

Comment: You are trying to stringify a collection of 2 strings, that won't do, since JSON.stringify expects an OBJECT to stringify. 

See my answer below for correct syntax ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you want? Do you want JSON-serialized strings embedded within JSON?

```
var JsonString = JSON.stringify({
  'candiates' : JSON.stringify($scope.candidates),
  'managers'  : JSON.stringify($scope.managers)
};)
```

Or do you just want one large JSON object with both `candidates` and `managers` as JSON lists?

```
var JsonString = JSON.stringify({
  'candiates' : $scope.candidates,
  'managers'  : $scope.managers
};)
```

Answer (score 4):

JSON is a format, there is no "JSON object".

Create the whole object that you want to send and then generate the JSON string:

```
var myObj= {
  candidates: $scope.candidates,
  managers: $scope.managers
}

var myJson=JSON.stringify(myObj);
```

Answer (score 1):

why not:

```
var JsonString = JSON.stringify({ 
      candidates: $scope.candidates, 
      managers: $scope.managers 
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a single object then stringify that object!

```
var both = {
   candidates : $scope.candidates,
   managers : $scope.managers
}
```

then:

```
var JsonString = JSON.stringify(both)
```

Remember JSON.stringify works on objects, not collections or strings.